# Arduino Software not finding our board in Tools->Serial Port on OS X Yosemite

Tags: arduino

I purchased this [extruder controller board](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Extruder_Controller_2.2#Burn_the_Bootloader) and this [board](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USBtinyISP-USBTiny-ISP-programmer-for-Arduino-bootloader-AVR-w-cable-6-10pin-/141227177601?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20e1cbb681) to connect it to the computer. I am following the [tutorial](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Extruder_Controller_2.2#Burn_the_Bootloader) above in trying to set it up. We successfully did the boot loader part of that tutorial and the DEBUG LED is flashing. I followed the tutorial all the way up to uploading the program. The Arduino software does not find it in "Tools -> Serial Port", but allows me to burn the bootlegger. The only options are a couple bluetooth devices I have connected, none of which are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am only aware of [windows drivers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/) for the ISP programmer board you're using. When I've ordered funky hardware off of eBay with a non-existent or difficult-to-find OSX driver, I've had success running Parallels. This is a funny work-around, but it might be your best bet -- many folks over on the Arduino.cc forums are having [the same problem](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=179144.0).

So: Curse the Gods. Buy parallels. Install windows. Install Atmel's official drivers. Burn your bootloader. Get back to building.

As always, if a serial port isn't showing up in the Arduino IDE, run the following command from Terminal:

```
ls /dev/tty* | grep 'usb'
```